# Problem with select option

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am getting the following Error:

> Error: Selectpick Compile Error: Constructor not defined:
>   [Selectoption].(String, String) at line 7 column 16

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="Selectpick">
<apex:form >
    <apex:selectlist value="{!sv}">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}"/>
    </apex:selectlist>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex Class:

```
public class Selectpick{
    public List<selectoption> getOptions() {
        List<selectoption> ls= new List<selectoption>();
        ls.add(new selectoption('none','--select--'));

        return ls;
    }

    public String sv { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: Recompile or delete and save .It got compiled and saved and working in my org .

Answer (score 4):

Do you have a class called "SelectOption"? If so, it is shadowing the default system class. You may need to refer to it as System.SelectOption instead.